# Minimizing the number of groups by merging them without exceding a certain group size

Tags: algorithm, sorting, optimization, merge

Note: This is not a homework, it's for an internship project.

---

Situation:

You have a list of `n` groups of varying sizes,
No group can contain more than `X` elements,

Say you have a function `merge(G1, G2)` which adds all elements of group `G2` into group `G1`       and removes `G2` from the list of groups.

EDIT: Every element member of a group is unique to all groups (i.e if group 1 has an elemen a; a does not exist in any other group)

---

Problem:

You need to minimize the number of groups by merging groups whose combined size is smaller than `X`

---

My initial thought:

To use a greedy algorithm that functions as follows:

```
sort the arrays by decreasing order, 

Then while array.size > 0:

   Pop largest group (lets call it GL) from the main list, and add it to a toBig list

   Then loop through the array until you find a group that can be merged with GL

      Merge the groups and add the merged group to a toRemove list

      Keep going and merging any group that fits

   once loop ends, remove all groups in toRemove from the main list

Continue While Loop
```

What do you guys think about this approach, will it yield the minimum number of groups (or something close)? Is there a more elegant approach or a more efficient algorithm?

Thank you for the input

P.S. I attempted to search this problem but i have no idea what the name of the problem is, and searching a description of it on SE and google yielded no relevant results.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "group" and "merge"? Are you referring to sets (in which all elements are distinct, and merging would be a union of sets) or lists (which can have recurring elements, and merging would be essentially appending one list to the other)?

Comment: Yes exactly no memeber of a group is a memeber of another.

The real situation: I used Krager's algorithm to find a min cut of a graph that caps the groups at a certain number of nodes X, however, some groups have no edges connecting to eachother but the sum of their sizes is smaller than X, hence it would be adgantageous for me to group them even though they dont have a connecting edge.

Comment: Sorry i misread your question, the second assumption was correct, merging is simply appending one list to the other.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is a Bin-packing problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), which unfortunately is NP-hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the actual element values don't matter as far as the solution goes.  They're merely a merging detail.  The only thing that matters is the *number* of elements in the group.  In other words, create a "count list" that just has the counts.

Sort the list. Lowest-to-highest or highest-to-lowest, it doesn't matter.  We're going to "pop" off the high end.  Let's call the count list `ginp` and the output list `gout`.  Let's call the popped element `gbig`.

So, if gbig is of size X, just add it to gout.  Keep popping until we have gout < X.  Now traverse ginp, hi-to-lo, call this `gtry`.  If (gtry + gbig) <= X, merge gtry into gbig. If gbig hits X, add to gout and start again.  Note that since gbig will be getting smaller, it becomes easier to merge more and more.

Do this until ginp is exhausted.  This is a "first fit" algorithm.  It's a baseline to work from.  Because of the sort, it may even be the best solution, but I suspect that you'll need a "best fit" which is a bit more complicated.

Consider an alternate strategy.  With a given gbig and given ginp, they form a "current state".  Suppose [hi-to-lo sort], that after gbig is popped, that ginp[0] will fit.  In the first fit, we took it.

But, suppose we skipped it [just for grins], and chose ginp[1] instead as gtry and took that.  Now, for the next addition to gbig, we can chose ginp[2] [if it fits], or we can skip.  Repeat this for the remaining ginp (either select or skip) until the either gbig hits X or we've moved past the end of ginp.

At the end, now pop another gbig and repeat, using only the elements not selected in the previous round.  Note that you just keep recursing until ginp is finally exhausted.  At each step, we select a fit from the remaining.  Doing this recursively forms a [binary] tree (based on take/skip) that will enumerate all possible selections.  Note that some nodes will not have a take because the next element in ginp is too big (e.g. gbig would overflow X)

Within this recursion, when ginp is exhausted, keep the minimum value for count of elements in gout (it too just needs to be a count).  The path to the root node gives you what you need:  the list of merge actions, etc.  Save that anytime you get a new minimum gout.

The maximum tree depth will be <= `n`

**UPDATE:** Need test data?  Here's a generator program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# grpgen -- generate test data for group reduction problem
#
# arguments:
#   "-X" - maximum value for X
#   "-n" - maximum value for n
#   "-T" - number of tests to generate
#   "-O" - output file
#   "-f" -- generate full element data
#
# NOTE: with no arguments or missing arguments will prompt

master(@ARGV);
exit(0);

# master -- master control
sub master
{
    local(@argv) = @_;

    select(STDOUT);
    $| = 1;

    $Xmax = getstr(2,"-X","maximum for X");
    $nmax = getstr(2,"-n","maximum for n");
    $tstmax = getstr(2,"-T","number of tests");
    $keyf = getstr(1,"-f","generate full element data");
    $ofile = getstr(0,"-O","output file name");

    open($xfdst,">$ofile") ||
        die("master: unable to open '$ofile' -- $!\n");

    for ($tstcur = 1;  $tstcur <= $tstmax;  ++$tstcur) {
        gentest();
    }

    close($xfdst);
}

# getstr -- get a string/number
sub getstr
{
    my($numflg,$opt,$prompt) = @_;
    my($arg);
    my($askflg);
    my($val);

    {
        # search command line for -whatever
        foreach $arg (@argv) {
            if ($arg =~ /^$opt(.*)$/) {
                $val = $1;
                $val = 1
                    if ($numflg && ($val eq ""));
                last;
            }
        }
        last if (defined($val));

        $askflg = 1;

        while (1) {
            printf("Enter ")
                if ($numflg != 1);

            printf("%s",$prompt);

            if ($numflg == 1) {
                printf(" (0/1)? ");
            }
            else {
                printf(": ");
            }

            $val = <STDIN>;
            chomp($val);

            if ($numflg == 0) {
                last if ($val ne "");
                next;
            }

            next unless ($val =~ /^\d+$/);
            $val += 0;

            last if ($val > 0);
            last if ($numflg == 1);
        }
    }

    unless ($askflg) {
        printf("%s: %s\n",$prompt,$val);
    }

    $val;
}

# gentest -- generate a test
sub gentest
{
    local($lhs);
    local($pre);

    $Xlim = getrand($Xmax);
    $xfmt = fmtof($Xlim);

    $nlim = getrand($nmax);
    $nfmt = fmtof($nlim);

    printf($xfdst "\n");
    printf($xfdst "T=%d X=%d n=%d\n",$tstcur,$Xlim,$nlim);

    for ($nidx = 1;  $nidx <= $nlim;  ++$nidx) {
        $xcur = getrand($Xmax);
        if ($keyf) {
            gengrpx();
        }
        else {
            gengrp();
        }
    }

    genout();
}

# gengrp -- generate group (counts only)
sub gengrp
{
    my($rhs);

    $rhs = sprintf($xfmt,$xcur);
    genout($rhs);
}

# gengrpx -- generate group (with element data)
sub gengrpx
{
    my($elidx,$rhs);

    $pre = sprintf("$nfmt:",$nidx);

    # NOTE: this is all irrelevant semi-junk data, so just wing it
    for ($elidx = 1;  $elidx <= $xcur;  ++$elidx) {
        $rhs = sprintf($xfmt,$elidx);
        genout($rhs);
    }

    genout();
}

# genout -- output data
sub genout
{
    my($rhs) = @_;

    {
        if (defined($rhs)) {
            last if ((length($pre) + length($lhs) + length($rhs)) < 78);
        }

        last if ($lhs eq "");

        print($xfdst $pre,$lhs,"\n");
        undef($lhs);
    }

    $lhs .= $rhs
        if (defined($rhs));
}

# getrand -- get random number
sub getrand
{
    my($lim) = @_;
    my($val);

    $val = int(rand($lim));
    $val += 1;

    $val;
}

# fmtof -- get number format
sub fmtof
{
    my($num) = @_;
    my($fmt);

    $fmt = sprintf("%d",$num);
    $fmt = length($fmt);
    $fmt = sprintf(" %%%dd",$fmt);

    $fmt;
}
```

Comment: I like the recursion idea as it explores all possibilities, however i haven't been given much test data so i dont know how feasable this will be since it will definintley be longer. Ill have to pester my boss for client data and try it out. Thanks!

Comment: @FrankO'Brien Posted a test data generator for you.  It's a perl script, so you can tell your friends that you used one :-).  I've been experimenting with similar algorithms and dynamic programming solutions to run faster than tree walk, so I may take a whack at this myself.  What are your known/preferred langs in decreasing order of knowledge.  List multiple:  I hate java, and I recently taught myself python [and what I found makes me not a fan].  I might prototype in perl and then do C.  Also, for the first fit, a variant [probably bad] is to take gtry lo-to-hi.  Try and compare

Comment: Unfortunately, the entire thing has to be done in java, its the company standard

Comment: @FrankO'Brien Ouch :-) Having the gen program can catch edge cases that client data won't.  Can you recode the perl into java?    Given script and its inputs/outputs, should be easy enough.  This is a necessary/valuable skill.  Either hack up or use as model.  I've taken java and recoded into C or perl before--usually there are parallel constructs.  Rise above syntax.  For example, simple C can be easily recoded as one big java class with everything as static.  After that works, cleaned up, and split into "better" java.

Answer (score 0):

In your problem, you never really care about the groups themselves, but rather their sizes. So I suggest we first rewrite the problem as a simpler yet equivalent problem with only integers: We will replace groups by their sizes, and replace the `merge` function by addition.

I will first give a simpler version of your algorithm (does the same thing if I understood it correctly), just because it ignores the irrelevant stuff like the groups themselves, the implementation details, etc. I will then give an example that shows why the algorithm is not optimal, and finally show how it is in fact within a factor of 2 of the optimal solution.

## Algorithm

```
Input: the integer x>0 and a list of positive integers

Do
    Find two numbers whose sum is less than x
    Merge them
Repeat the above until no such two numbers exist
Return the final list
```

## Why it is not optimal

Consider the following input:

```
x = 10
list: (3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4)
```

In this case, the optimal solution would be to add ("merge") two `3`'s and a `4`, twice, giving `(3+3+4, 3+3+4)`, i.e., `(10, 10)`.

However, your solution might decide to add the two `4`'s together, which will result in the new list `(9, 1, 8)`, which is longer than `(10, 10)`.
In fact, even if you decide to always add the two largest numbers or the two smallest numbers, you would get the same result.
For any similar scheme I could think of, I could always come up with a counter-example.

## Why it is approximately optimal

Your algorithm will always result in a list that contains at most **one** element that is less than or equal to `floor(x/2)`. Indeed, if there were two such elements, the algorithm will find them and add them.

If your solution list had a size of `m`, then it follows that the total sum of all the elements is **at least** `m*floor(x/2)`. Call this number `S`.
However, any optimal solution *must* have at least `ceil(S/x)` elements (otherwise they won't all be less than `x`). Therefore:

```
optimal >= ceil(S/x) >= ceil( m * floor(x/2) / x )
        >= m*floor(x/2)/x ~ m/2
```

Thus the algorithm is within a factor of `2` of the optimal solution.

Comment: Im not 100% clear, you suggest that sorting will actually lead to worse solutions than taking the groups as is?

Comment: That's not quite what I meant. My point was that sorting won't necessarily do better, and it certainly can be sub-optimal as in the example I gave. However, whether you sort or not, you will always be within a factor of 2.